# How to call setChecked for RadioButton of specific position in RecyclerView (Adapter) java?

Tags: android

I hope you are fine.

i need to use setChecked for RadioButton in RecyclerView Adapter, from another class, i could not do that. i hope you help me.

this is my Adapter (in this adapter all is working fine I just need to set Checked the radio button of specific position from another class, how can i do that ?):

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    public int mSelectedItem = -1;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mItems;
    private Context mContext;
    public static ClickListener clickListener;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        View v = viewHolder.itemView;
        RadioButton radiobutton1 = v.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton1);
        radiobutton1.setChecked(i == mSelectedItem);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams _lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        v.setLayoutParams(_lp);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_adapter, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public RadioButton mRadio;
        public TextView mText;

        public ViewHolder(final View inflate) {
            super(inflate);
            mText = (TextView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.title);
            mRadio = (RadioButton) inflate.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton1);
            View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Adapter.clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
                    mSelectedItem = getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
            itemView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            mRadio.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(Adapter.ClickListener clickListener) {
        Adapter.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure on Android specifically, but I imagine is similar to Java. In Java, you add an Event Listener to the component (i.e. Button). The event object contains a reference to the component where the action was triggered from. You can then use that object to set the state after on click event takes place. For Radio Buttons specifically might be a bit different because (in Java) radio buttons are typically added to a Radio Button Group and the selection/deselection is delegated to this class so that it can enforce single selection rule with regards to the members of the group.

Comment: @hfontanez thanks brother, i got idea but i'm still unable to implement it, i need a simple java example, maybe our brothers here show me how 
thanks again

Comment: I can show you a Java Swing example, but not Android since I am not an Android developer nor I have an Android development environment set up.

Comment: @hfontanez yes my brother, I be thankful, show me the java swing example and I get an idea at least and I try to apply the way  on android

Comment: I just made a correction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how this is done using Java Swing (as requested by the OP)

```
public class RadioButtonDemo {
    
    JPanel radioPanel = null;
    
    public RadioButtonDemo() {
        RadioButtonListener listener = new RadioButtonListener();
        
        JRadioButton btnOne = new JRadioButton("One");
        JRadioButton btnTwo = new JRadioButton("Two");
        JRadioButton btnThree = new JRadioButton("Three");
        
        btnOne.addActionListener(listener);
        btnTwo.addActionListener(listener);
        btnThree.addActionListener(listener);

        btnOne.setSelected(true);
        
        ButtonGroup btnGp = new ButtonGroup();
        btnGp.add(btnOne);
        btnGp.add(btnTwo);
        btnGp.add(btnThree);
        
        radioPanel = new JPanel();
        radioPanel.add(btnOne);
        radioPanel.add(btnTwo);
        radioPanel.add(btnThree);

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        RadioButtonDemo demo = new RadioButtonDemo();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(demo.radioPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private static class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JRadioButton btn = (JRadioButton)e.getSource();
            System.out.println("Selected button: " + btn.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I don't need to explicitly select or deselect buttons in a radio button group.

[image]

Comment: humm, thank you so much, i really got idéa, i will re-read it again and again trying to apply the same idea on android

Comment: @Hasni Just remember that if you want each radio button to fire off a distinct action, you can create a listener for each radio button. In this example I only used one because I wanted all radio buttons to do the same thing on click. It is up to you to decide which approach you need.